# Can't authenticate for Windows file sharing

Tags: windows-vista, file-sharing

I'm trying to access a default administrative share

`\\host\n$`

hosted on a Vista Ultimate machine from a Windows 7 box (though my XP machine has the same problem). I'm prompted for a username and password, so far so good. I enter **HOST\Jerph** as my username (edit: it's a local administrator account) and the correct password, but I get access denied over and over again. I know the password is right. This has been happening for as long as I've had Vista on this machine.

I can successfully access explicit shares by giving Everyone read access. It does not prompt for a password in that case, as expected, but I obviously don't like doing that. How do I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: what login are you entering? does it belong to the Windows Vista machine as a local account?

Comment: Yes, a local administrator account.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Administrative shares are disabled by default in Vista. You can enable them by browsing the registry to

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`

Add a new DWORD called `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` with a value of 1 and reboot.

Comment: Another superuser success story

Comment: this has driven me crazy for MONTHS! Thank you. This is also the default in Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 5):

It's not that administrative shares are disabled, it's that Local Administrators do not have permissions to access administrative shares over the network. It has been this way since Vista onward. You can change it with the registry entry CGA specified:

1. Click start
2. Type: regedit
3. Press enter
4. In the left, browse to the following folder:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system\`
5. Right-click a blank area in the right pane
6. Click New
7. Click DWORD Value
8. Type: LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy
9. Double-click the item you just created
10. Type 1 into the box
11. Click OK
12. Restart your computer