# Can't authenticate to shared network resource

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

There is a Windows 7 desktop PC with a shared folder on the root of the C drive (C:\sharename).  This folder has Everyone with read/write access.

A Windows 7 laptop normally has a drive mapped to this folder as \hostname\sharename

Today, this mapping failed.  A troubleshooter showed the connection was being rejected by the desktop PC.

I unmapped it, and remapped the drive, authenticating as a different user, and specifying a hostname\localusername as the user account (a local user account on the desktop PC).

This also failed.

Can you think why the original drive mapping would fail if Everyone has read/write access?

Can you think why the new drive mapping would fail if the localusername on hostname has read/write access?

I don't think the solutions listed [in this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/74512/cant-authenticate-for-windows-file-sharing) apply, as the folder is not an administrative share, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling Sophos Firewall/AntiVirus and McAfee AntiVirus removed the symptoms, so one of them was causing the problem.

I could then browse both \hostname and \IP_address, and remap the drive.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that there are no IP conflicts on the host  PC and the client PC? I wouldn't use open access with the group everyone - it would be much securer for future references to specifiy accounts or account groups. Have you checked that both PCs have network connectivity. This article *may* help. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Troubleshoot-network-connection-problems. Hope this helps.

Comment: What do you mean by IP conflicts Jake?

Comment: Check that they aren't using the same IP (although a message would be shown in the taskbar), or checl that they are both configured correctly, eg, if one is 192.168.1.1 and the others 169.254.x.x then you have an error there.

Comment: Thanks, there are no conflicts and they're in the same subnet.

Comment: Have you tried mapping to the IP address instead of the host name?

Comment: Also, if you ping the hostname from command prompt what does it say? Open command prompt, "ping 192.168.1.1" etc

Comment: Yes, I have tried mapping the IP address but the same problem occurs.  I can ping the IP fine.

Comment: What is the error displayed if you connect to the PC via the run command? \\hostname\sharename

Comment: It just said Windows could not connect to sharename.  I uninstalled Sophos Firewall/AntiVirus, and McAfee AntiVirus, and the symptoms disappeared.

Comment: Wait, did you have two antiviruses? If you did that is not a good idea as there is a good chance they will clash. Please upvote this post as well as posting your answer. Thank you, Jake

Comment: The previous IT person installed them, not me.  :-P

Comment: I'm guessing you have sinced installed an antivirus though?